# Необходимость наличия подключения к интернету

Tags: python, symbian

Здравствуйте. На аппарате Nokia n8-00 столкнулся с проблемой: python script shell для python 2.0 при запуске инициирует соединение с интернетом, что при отсутствии сигнала сети или автономном режиме приводит к вылету script shell. При этом в исходном коде default.py отсутствуют обращения к сетевым модулям. Чем это можно полечить? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На новых версиях Symbian стоят версии библиотеки PIPS, которые при запуске пытаются выйти в интернет, чтобы проверить наличие обновлений. Если подключения нет, то PIPS прекращает работу с ошибкой. Питон базируется на PIPS, поэтому его запуск тоже невозможен.
Возможно, в новых версиях PIPS баг был исправлен, но в 1.7.0 он еще был. Не могу сказать точно, перешел на андроид, который постоянно развивается в отличие от Symbian.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидный вариант, который напрашивается сразу - если Вы понимаете исходники на Питоне, то попробуйте просмотреть все (открытые) модули. Может быть, собака порыта где-нибудь в другой стороне?